# Search for strings in the prefix tree. Abstract suggest

Tags: algorithm, scala, tree

I'm working with a prefix tree algorithm.
It should offer me all the words that contain a word from input.
I have some problems with adding new words to the tree. This is due to gaps in Scala knowledge.
Can you tell me how to fix it?

My class:

```
  class SuggestService(companyNames : Seq[String]) {

  val ternary = Ternary.apply
                       .insert("Googland")   //This word is added.
                       .insert("GoogleMaps") //This word is added.
  ternary.insert("GooglePhone") //This word is not added.
  ternary.insert("Google")      //This word is not added.

  def suggest(input: String, numberOfSuggest : Int) : Seq[String] = {
    val result = ternary.keysWithPrefix("Goog")
    result
  }
}
```

After launching, I get:

```
result == List(Googland, GoogleMaps)
```

Although I expect to get:

```
result == List(Googland, GoogleMaps, GooglePhone, Google)
```

Tree class:

```
sealed trait Ternary {
  def insert(key: String): Ternary = Ternary.insert(this, key, 0)

  def keysWithPrefix(prefix: String): List[String] = Ternary.keys(this, prefix)
}

case class Node(value: Option[Int], char: Char, left: Ternary, mid: Ternary, right: Ternary) extends Ternary

case object Leaf extends Ternary

object Ternary {
  def apply: Ternary = Leaf

  private def keys(root: Ternary, prefix: String): List[String] =
    get(root, prefix, 0) match {
      case None => Nil
      case Some(node) =>
        collect(node, prefix.dropRight(1))
    }

  private def collect(node: Ternary, prefix: String): List[String] =
    node match {
      case Leaf => Nil
      case node: Node if node.value.isDefined =>
        (prefix + node.char) +: (collect(node.left, prefix) ++ collect(node.mid, prefix + node.char) ++ collect(node.right, prefix))
      case node: Node =>
        collect(node.left, prefix) ++ collect(node.mid, prefix + node.char) ++ collect(node.right, prefix)
    }

  private def get(root: Ternary, prefix: String, step: Int): Option[Ternary] = root match {
    case Leaf => None
    case node: Node if node.char > prefix.charAt(step) => get(node.left, prefix, step)
    case node: Node if node.char < prefix.charAt(step) => get(node.right, prefix, step)
    case node: Node if step < prefix.length - 1 => get(node.mid, prefix, step + 1)
    case node: Node => Some(node)
  }

  private def insert(root: Ternary, key: String, step: Int): Ternary = root match {
    case Leaf =>
      val node = Node(None, key.charAt(step), Leaf, Leaf, Leaf)
      insert(node, key, step)

    case node: Node if node.char > key.charAt(step) =>
      val left = insert(node.left, key, step)
      node.copy(left = left)

    case node: Node if node.char < key.charAt(step) =>
      val right = insert(node.right, key, step)
      node.copy(right = right)

    case node: Node if step < key.length - 1 =>
      val mid = insert(node.mid, key, step + 1)
      node.copy(mid = mid)

    case node: Node =>
      node.copy(value = Some(0))
  }
}
```

Comment: `Ternary.apply.insert(...` builds and returns a new `Ternary` instance which is then saved in the `ternary` variable. `ternary.insert(...` does the same. It **returns** a new (modified) `Ternary` instance but the returned value isn't being saved anywhere so it is discarded. The variable `ternary` is immutable and unchanged.

Comment: @jwvh, Now I understand what's going on. But can I somehow push the companyNames collection into a tree? Maybe by recursion somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternative solution to my problem.
But I am interested in what is the complexity of performing `the set.range(prefix, succ(prefix))` operation.
And can I overwrite the range method to return a limited set using the numberOfSuggest variable?

```
class SuggestService(companyNames : Seq[String]) {

  val tree = new Tree
  companyNames.foreach(tree.add)

  def suggest(input: String, numberOfSuggest : Int) : Seq[String] = {
    val result = tree.findMatches(input, numberOfSuggest)
    result.toSeq
  }
}
```

Tree class:

```
import scala.collection.immutable._
class Tree {

  private var set = new TreeSet[String]()
  private def succ(s : String) = s.take(s.length - 1) + (s.charAt(s.length - 1) + 1).toChar

  def add(s: String): Unit = set += s

  def findMatches(prefix: String, numberOfSuggest: Int): Set[String] =
    if (prefix.isEmpty)
      set
    else
      set.range(prefix, succ(prefix))
}
```